# Passing parameter to component. Use brackets or not

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 6 have the following component:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() type: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

}
```

The HTML of the component is the following:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<p *ngIf="type=='admin'">Admin Message</p>
```

And I am using the component as follows:

```
<header [type]="admin"></header>
```

The message does not show unless I remove the brackets around type:

```
<header type="admin"></header>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When you use `[type]`, the value must be an expression. For it to work like that, you'd need `[type]="'admin'"`(note the `'`s that make it a string). When you use `[type]="admin"`, you're asking Angular to look for an `admin` property on your hosting component and use its value.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I see. But should I use [type]=“‘admin’” or type=“admin”. I mean both work. What would be the consequence of using one or another? I am missing that ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Without the brackets, the value is treated as a string constant

```
    prop1="val1" // the string "val1" is assigned to prop1
```

- With the brackets, the value is an expression that is evaluated

```
    [prop1]="val1"   // the value of the class property val1 is assigned to prop1
    [prop1]="val1()" // the value returned by the method val1() is assigned to prop1
    [prop1]="'val1'" // the string "val1" is assigned to prop1
    [prop1]="condition ? val1() : 'val2'" // the result is assigned to prop1
```

---

From the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets):

> **Remember the brackets**
>
> The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the
> template expression. If you omit the brackets, Angular treats the
> string as a constant and initializes the target property with that
> string. It does not evaluate the string!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass hard code string from then it should be

```
<header type="'admin'"></header>
```

But if the value admin is a variable inside your component.ts file then, in that case, you should write

```
hero.component.ts

export class HeroComponent {
    admin: string = "Administrator";
}

<header [type]="admin"></header>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<header [type]="admin"></header>
```

Admin is being considered an attribute of your parent component and not a string value. What you want is to pass it in as a string, so instead you would say:

```
<header [type]="'admin'"></header>
```